# rails should i push schema.rb file for new created migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, schema

I am working on rails 4 application and I am working with 4 more other developers. We all can generate the migration and create tables. We maintain our code on git repo.

So while creating a new migration should we push our schema.rb file ti git repo. OR I need to write it in gitignore file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not have to push the schema.rb file. When you run the migrations and other stuffs in the server the schema automatically get updated.

Even if u push the schema.rb file no problem happens.